# display a view when an activity starts

Tags: android, view, dismiss

I need to display a certain view when an activity starts, and when the user click `ckecked` to dismiss the view. It look like this

: [image]

Has anyone an idea how can I do this? Any idea is welcome.

Comment: create custom dialog and open it when activity starts...

Comment: you can have custom dialog with checkbox like: http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-alertdialog-with-checkbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create custom dialog using below link and open it when activity starts...

you need to increase the margin to proivde more spaces

Have a look at custom dialog examples -

[custom dialog 1](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application)

[custom dialog 2](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: How can I increase the margin to provide more spaces?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use a custom [dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

just create a custom XML and inflate it into your dialog object

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

dialog.show();
```

and then dismiss it by calling `dialog.dismiss();`

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) for Creating window

see these tutorila for adding PopupWindow in your Activity:

[Using the PopupWindow class in Android apps](http://www.mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/)

[Example of using PopupWindow](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `RelativeLayout` for this. When the user clicks `check`, the `visibility` of the 'upper' layout must be set to `GONE`.